# randomly display these questions without repeat

Tags: java

I want to display the 15 questions randomly without repeating, with the first 5 randomly displaying first as easy, then next 5 as medium, then last 5 as hard. However, I need to print them out without repeating them and also make sure before the medium and hard questions get printed, all the easy questions are printed first. I've seen things about collections.shuffle() but I'd like to implement this without using that because I don't really understand it. If anyone could help thanks. Here's my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class WWTBAM {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Welcome to 'Who Wants to be a Millionaire'!");
    System.out.println("There will be a total of 15 questions.");
    System.out.println("You must answer all of them correctly in order to win the grand prize of $1 000 000!");
    System.out.println("This round's theme will be basketball, and the questions get harder and harder.");
    System.out.println("To help with your journey, you have one of each: 50:50, call a friend, ask the audience.");
    System.out.println("To use 50:50 enter 1, to use call a friend enter 2, to use ask the audience enter 3.");
    System.out.println("You also have the option to leave with your money after every question by entering 0.");
    System.out.println("For each question, answer either a, b, c or d.");
    System.out.println("Good luck!\n");

    String[] questions = new String[15];
    questions[0] = "How do you score points in basketball?\n a) Shoot a ball in a net\n b) Hit a birdie with a racquet\n c) Kick a ball across the field\n d) Knockout the opposing players\n";
    questions[1] = "How many players does a team have playing on an NBA court at one time?\n a) 6\n b) 10\n c) 5\n d) 3\n";
    questions[2] = "Which team won the 2016-2017 NBA championship?\n a) Cleveland Cavaliers\n b) Golden State Warriors\n c) Toronto Raptors\n d) Boston Celtics\n";
    questions[3] = "Which team does Lamarcus Aldridge currently play for?\n a) Houston Rockets\n b) Portland Trailblazers\n c) Memphis Grizzlies\n d) San Antonio Spurs\n";
    questions[4] = "How many total teams are there in the NBA currently?\n a) 10\n b) 25\n c) 30\n d) 20\n";

    questions[5] = "How many NBA championships has Michael Jordan won?\n a) 5\n b) 6\n c) 7\n d) 8\n";
    questions[6] = "Who holds the record for most points scored in one game?\n a) Kobe Bryant\n b) Wilt Chamberlain\n c) Michael Jordan\n d) Bill Russell\n";
    questions[7] = "What division are the Toronto Raptors in?\n a) Central Division\n b) Southeast Division\n c) Pacific Division\n d) Atlantic Division\n";
    questions[8] = "Which team has the most amount of championships in history?\n a) Los Angeles Lakers\n b) Chicago Bulls\n c) Boston Celtics\n d) Miami Heat\n";
    questions[9] = "Who is the youngest player to ever win the MVP award?\n a) LeBron James\n b) Derrick Rose\n c) Stephen Curry\n d) Kawhi Leonard\n";

    questions[10] = "Which team won the 1994-1995 NBA championship?\n a) Houston Rockets\n b) Chicago Bulls\n c) Orlando Magic\n d) Phoenix Suns\n";
    questions[11] = "What is the current NBA championship trophy called?\n a) Chris MacFord Trophy\n b) Walter A. Brown Trophy\n c) Larry O’Brien Trophy \n d) Jolly Mazgard Trophy\n";
    questions[12] = "Which player won the iconic 1988 3-pt contest?\n a) Drazen Petrovic\n b) Peja Stojakovic\n c) Larry Bird\n d) Pete Maravich\n";
    questions[13] = "Which player is nicknamed “The Glove” in the NBA?\n a) Gary Payton\n b) Reggie Miller\n c) Charles Barkley\n d) Shawn Kemp\n";
    questions[14] = "In which year was the NBA founded?\n a) 1943\n b) 1944\n c) 1945\n d) 1946\n";
    String[] answers = {"a", "c", "b", "d", "c", "b", "b", "d", "c", "b", "a", "c", "c", "a", "d"};

    int[] money = {100, 200, 500, 750, 1500, 3000, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 50000, 100000, 200000, 500000, 1000000};
    int random;
    String response;
    String name;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();

    System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
    name = sc.nextLine();


    for (int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {

        if (i > 9) {
            random = rand.nextInt(5) + 10;
        } else if (i > 4) {
            random = rand.nextInt(5) + 5;
        } else {
            random = rand.nextInt(5) + 0;
        }
        System.out.println(questions[random]);
        response = sc.nextLine();


        if (!response.equalsIgnoreCase(answers[random])) {
            System.out.println("You lost! Too bad too sad.");
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You're basically asking for an implementation of `Collections.shuffle`.  I understand that you don't want to _call_ `Collections.shuffle`, but why don't you look at the source code for `Collections.shuffle` to see how it does its work?

Comment: He already said that easy ones should print before the medium and hard ones. The `Collections.shuffle` might not be the best choice as this a special case.

Comment: Sure, so he'll have to make three separate collections and shuffle each of them separately.  So `Collections.shuffle` is still the right solution.  And if he doesn't want to use `Collections.shuffle`, then he can still study the source code and see how to do shuffling.

Comment: _"... about collections.shuffle() but I'd like to implement this without using that because I don't really understand it"_ - While the goal is admirable, don't you think the best place to start would be by studying the code for `Collections.shuffle()`?  Asking for something like that here is off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site.

Answer (score 0):

You can create three `HashMap`'s, one for easy, medium and hard. Populate them with question as key and answer as value.

EDIT:

Do this for easy, then medium and for hard questions `HashMap`.

Get their key set for one `HashMap`. Add them to an empty list, perform a `Collections.shuffle()`, loop the `ArrayList`, and get the keys from the original `HashMap`. Below is the tested sample code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();    
        hm.put("1a", "z");
        hm.put("s4", "x");
        hm.put("4d", "c");
        hm.put("ef", "v");
        hm.put("g6", "b");
        hm.put("8h", "b");

        System.out.println("The same 'random' order of questions:");
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry: hm.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " "+ entry.getValue());
        }

        new MyClass().shuffleQuestions(hm);
        new MyClass().shuffleQuestions(hm);
        new MyClass().shuffleQuestions(hm);
    }

    public void shuffleQuestions(HashMap<String, String> hm){
        System.out.println("\nShuffled Questions with answers:");
        Set<String> s = hm.keySet();
        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        arr.addAll(s);
        Collections.shuffle(arr);
        for(String s1: arr){
            System.out.println(s1 + " " + hm.get(s1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might find out that the order is always the _same_ "random" order, though.

Comment: @Marvin, you've made the point. Yes, the order would be the _same_ "random" for my previous answer. But I've updated my answer that includes _real_ shuffling :)

Comment: @Brian, does this solve your question? You can simply use the `shuffleQuestions( )` for different categories of questions, viz. **easy**, **medium** and **hard**.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Collections.shuffle()`

> Don't forget to fill collection with element before shuffling

Example:

```
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));
    System.out.println("Init: " + Arrays.toString(numbers.toArray()));
    Collections.shuffle(numbers);
    System.out.println("Result: " + Arrays.toString(numbers.toArray()));
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 5, 6, 4, 2, 1]
```